# Can't open Hartl's sample_app on local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm going trough Hartl's tutorial and everything was ok until 11th chapter. I did everything in chapter 11 as was required(few times, maybe that is problem?) and suddenly I can't open app on local server.
Problems begun when i was supposed to seed database, so I reset it and (unsuccessfully) seeded it few times. Finally, i managed to seed db, but problem remained.

This is what i get on local server but I don't know what are this arguments:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) for `asset-path' (in /home/aki/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss:1)

Extracted source (around line #1):

$iconSpritePath: asset-path('glyphicons-halflings.png', image);
$iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-url("glyphicons-halflings-white.png", image);

@import "bootstrap";

Rails.root: /home/aki/sample_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss:1
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2752615510238668489_70204869722340'
```

If you need 'insight' in other files, I will post them, I don't know where is problem.. Please help :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, my answer should help you solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Understanding errors

First of all, it's important that you learn to read & understand error messages properly:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) for `asset-path` (in 
/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss:1)
```

This basically says, there are 2 arguments for the `asset-path` helper, but only 1 is expected. It does not know what to do with the second argument.

It also shows where this error exists, giving you the exact path to the file with the error: *bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss*

### The error itself

So after you learned that, you can open the file and change your code from:

```
$iconSpritePath: asset-path('glyphicons-halflings.png', image);
$iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-url('glyphicons-halflings-white.png', image);
```

to:

```
$iconSpritePath: asset-path('glyphicons-halflings.png');
$iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-url('glyphicons-halflings-white.png');
```

I simply removed the second argument, `image`. The `asset-path` & `asset-url` helpers only take one *single* argument, as stated in the error and [described in their docs](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#asset-helpers).

Comment: Thanks, it worked, you are true Champ! :) I don't know why that 'image' argument is there though..